# Ng-init via function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-init

As you know, it is possible to initialize objects as follows:

```
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>
```

Is it possible to define object similar like this but via a function:

```
<div ng-init="init()">
```

My aim is actually taking the objects from an API and show them in a list via ng-repeat

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit) says `ng-init` will take any expression. So yes, you can do what you want above as long as the associated scope defines a function called `init()` (and I also verified it for fun).

Note that the documentation says that `ng-init` is really only intended to be used for aliasing properties inside of an `ng-repeat`:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit for aliasing special properties of
>   ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use
>   controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Finally, note that you can simply initialize your variables when the controller is created. So there's really no need to use `ng-init` at all. For example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.a = 'Apples';
    $scope.b = 'Bees';
    $scope.c = 'Zebras';
  };
  // runs once per controller instantiation
  $scope.init();

}]);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for me. I did the exact same thing. My UI form has ng-models like object.a, object.b, etc... In my controller I have an init function and I have $scope.object.a='myValue', $scope.object.b='myValue' etc.. It says, it cannot find the property a. What am I missing here ?

Comment: @SandeepAllampalli Hard to say w/out seeing your code. But if I were to guess, you might need to initialize `$scope.object`, before you try to set a value on `$scope.object.a`. `$scope.object = {}; $scope.object.a = 'myValue';` Or `$scope.object = { a: 'myValue', b: 'myValue' };`

Comment: Right, I realized that later and a defined it as a json format, like $scope.object = { a: 'myValue', b: 'myValue' }; and it worked fine :) Thanks for responding though !

Comment: Maybe it would help if they renamed this ng-alias... or ng-assign... as it stands, they named it to be used for exactly what they tell developers not to use it for... getting mixed messages lol

Comment: I use ng-init for simple calculations per each item, for example, show person name I use a function, so it is cleaner code...

Answer (score 6):

> So there's really no need to use ng-init at all

Sometimes you would want to initialize something by passing data in the view, which might have its uses in a templated page such as .NET MVC, where you want to pass information from .NET to angular  (controller already has the data and the easiest way is to pass this in a ViewBag).

To do this the "correct" way is roundabout, and hard to maintain since you have to embed a script tag with a fixed ID on the page and use javascript/jquery to pull the data into your scope in your controller, again using the hard-coded ID.

Either way breaks (well, kludges) the MVW-pattern of angular, so, I guess, pick your poison.

Comment: Perhaps I should have worded "So there's really no need to use `ng-init` at all" better. There was no need for the OP to use `ng-init` in their case.

Comment: I also found one use case for `ng-init` when I wanted to load common localized text strings (data validation, global error messages etc.) from the server. I don't want to duplicate my PHP text arrays to JSON files and load them separately through XHR or create a new PHP controller action to return the texts separately. Ng-init seemed a good solution to load the texts at once with the frame of my SPA app and then store these texts to a global i18n Angular service, so they are available throughout my entire app.