# Create an array using ng-init angular js

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to create an array using `ng-init` dynamically?
The bellow code is not working

```
 ng-init="medi_count = new Array(5)"
```

Comment: don't use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for such initialization..keep this is controller would make more sense..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular expression is not same like JavaScript expression. It has some limits.!

> **No Object Creation With New Operator:** You cannot use new operator in an Angular expression.

Refer Angular Documentation : [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can its just the same way you create Arrays..

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-init="names=[{name:'Shijin',city:'NewYork'},   {name:'John',city:'Montana'},{name:'Phillip',city:'California'}]">
            <ul>
                  <font face="Impact" color="purple" size = "5"><li data-ng-repeat="Objects in names">{{Objects.name}} - {{Objects.city}}</li></font>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

ng-init is for loading data into an array, as other answer shows. If you just want a new empty array, then make it in the controller

```
 $scope.medi_count = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty fine by calling a function

```
<div ng-init="medicount(5)">
```

where

```
$scope.medicount = function(someNumber){
   //what you want
}
```

as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603869/ng-init-via-function)