# Failed initializing html tab with server data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init

I am creating an html page with two tabs.  When you click on tab 1, it loads table data 1.  When you click on tab 2,
it loads table data 2.  Tab 1 is working as expected.  However, when I click on tab 2, the data isn't loaded.  The controllers
are identical.  What is the difference?

Here is the relevant html code. tab with id "tableData" loads with data and tab with id "correlations" doesn't load.

```
        <div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#tableData" aria-controls="tableData" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Table Data</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#correlations" aria-controls="correlations" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Correlations</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tableData">
                    <h2 class="sub-header">Health Data</h2>
                    <div class="table-responsive" data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="journalCtrl">
                        <div data-ng-include="'screens/tablescreen.html'"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="correlations">
                    <h2 class="sub-header">Correlations Data</h2>
                    <div class="table-responsive" data-ng-app="correlationsApp" data-ng-controller="correlationsCtrl">
                        <div data-ng-include="'screens/tablescreen.html'"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my correlationsCtrl.  init() is never invoked.  Why?:

```
var correlationsApp = angular.module('correlationsApp', []);

correlationsApp.controller('correlationsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $http.get("https://localhost:4567/foo/1/correlations")
            .then(function (response) {
            var json = response.data.records;
            $scope.records = json;
            $scope.headers = response.data.headers;
        });
    };

    //This is not invoked.  Why?
    $scope.init();
});
```

Here is my controller which does get invoked:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('journalCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.init = function () {
        $http.get("https://localhost:4567/journal/1")
            .then(function (response) {
            var json = response.data.records;
            $scope.records = json;
            $scope.headers = response.data.headers;
        });
    };

    //This is invoked on page load.  Why does this work and the other doesn't?
    $scope.init();
});
```

Here is the html table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-ng-repeat="header in headers">{{header}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="record in records track by $index">
        <td data-ng-repeat="header in headers">{{ record.data[header] }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you may get help from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603869/ng-init-via-function

Comment: I have updated my question, removing ng-init since I don't think I need it.  I should be able to init right within my controller ... this works for tab 1 but not tab 2.  Not sure why - they seem identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html you declare `data-ng-controller="fooCtrl"` but you have no controller `fooCtrl`. No need to declare two different `module` for two tabs you can declare two `controller` for two tabs in same module.

like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('correlationsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        // your code
    };
    $scope.init();
}).controller('journalCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.init = function () {
       // your code
    };
    $scope.init();
});
```

so you use `ng-app = "myApp"` in root element like `<html ng-app="myApp">` or `<body ng-app="myApp">` and use only `data-ng-controller` in your tab page.

```
<div class="table-responsive" data-ng-controller="journalCtrl">
    <div data-ng-include="'screens/tablescreen.html'"></div>
 </div>
```

and

```
<div class="table-responsive" data-ng-controller="correlationsCtrl">
        <div data-ng-include="'screens/tablescreen.html'"></div>
</div>
```

[See PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/sWXmva6I4aM9lv5uEEAz?p=preview) two tabs show data from two different controllers.

Comment: That was a mistake in my example, but I don't have that problem in my "real" code.  The problem unfortunately is not this.  I have fixed the stackoverflow question - sorry I got it wrong the first time.

Comment: No, I have not solved the problem.  Still don't know why correlationCtrl.init() is never invoked.

Comment: can you try like plunker demo?

Comment: Your code example on Plunker worked fine.  I refactored my code to use only one app containing 2 controllers.  It now works.  Thanks for taking the time to make a clear plunker example.  Very helpful!